# Best way to avoid getting error in uploading a file

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> move_uploaded_file(/doc_2345.txt): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied

-This is the error when i try to upload a file and save it to database(MYSQL).
I'm new with creating a website using a framework. So i don't know how to fix it.

_form.

```
<div class="documents-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'reference_no')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_date')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_for')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_from')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'drawer_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_file')->fileInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

model.

```
public $file;
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'documents';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reference_no', 'subject', 'doc_date', 'doc_for', 'drawer_id','doc_from', 'doc_file'], 'required'],
        [['reference_no'], 'integer'],
        [['doc_date'], 'safe'],
        [['subject', 'doc_for', 'drawer_id','doc_from'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        [['doc_file'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
    ];
}
```

controller.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Documents();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))  {
        $model->save();
        $docuId = $model->reference_no;
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'doc_file');
        $docuName = 'doc_' . $docuId . '.' . $file->getExtension();
        $file -> saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/filesPath') . '/' . $docuName);
        $model -> doc_file = $docuName;
        $model -> save();

         return $this -> redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does '@webroot/filesPath' exist and is writtable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change folder permission and all other file & folders in which "filesPath" folder.

```
$file -> saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/filesPath') . '/' . $docuName);
```

I think it will solve your issue.